Intraclass correlation -- which one?
I have data collected from an employee survey, in which employees are asked to rate various aspects of their work experience (like engagement, collaboration, and teamwork). Each row is a record of an employee's response to a survey question. I also have a label for the Department they work in. For example:
Emp_Id    Department      Question        Response
1         Marketing       Collaboration   3
1         Marketing       Teamwork        4
2         Finance         Collaboration   4
2         Finance         Teamwork        3
2         Finance         Engagement      2
...

I would like to use intraclass correlations to determine if variance in their responses to each question is attributable more to their Department than the overall company culture. I am having trouble identifying the right type of ICC (1, 2, or 3) to calculate - most of the documentation speaks of "subjects" and "raters", and I am unsure how to "map" that paradigm to my current survey style data. A little assistance with understanding this is greatly appreciated.
For what it's worth, I am working in R, in case anyone uses example code in their response. Thank you!

Can you please explain what the survey response is; seems like Likert-style data? But you talk about variance? WE would need some clarity about the questions, responses, etc.

@jginestet Correct, each question is on a likert style scale (in this example, it is on a 5pt scale).

So your basic data is ordinal (Likert scale). Your question of interest is to see if the responses are due to department's culture, or overall company culture. In this context, your raters are the employees of each department; and in fact, the department itself (as you will aggregate all the employees of a given department, as you are not interested in employee-to-employee differences). And the objects (or subjects?) are the various questions (the things you are rating). As a first thought you would then pool all employees together (all ratings for a question) to represent the company, and compare this to all ratings from only a single department (for the same question). You can repeat for the different questions, and the different departments.
Note that here, you will have a different number of ratings for the company, and the departments; this is the major issue in your case (more on this later).
Another issue is that you have ordinal data (e.g. ICC’s are really for numeric data).
Additionally, there would be a (small?) correlation between a department and the company (because the company includes the counts for any given department). One could argue that the relative size of a department to the company is small, and neglect this. Or, for each department, take a subsample of its ratings, and assign them exclusively to the company, with the rest going to the department. But that reduces your sample size, and your power with it. Or, for the company’s ratings, use all employees, except the ones from the department in question. Now we have independence, no large impact on sample size, but the question this answers is a bit different; does a given department rate a question differently than the rest of the company? Which may be almost as good? This(comparing to “the rest of the company” is what I would do.
Last, I could not come up with an omnibus test which could answer your question (in great part because of the above issues: ordinal, independence, unequal sample sizes between 2 raters). So the best I could do is a series of 2-sample tests. But that implies multiple comparison corrections (MCC: Sidak?). E.g., if you have 10 questions, and 8 departments, that is 80 tests. Very large drop in power...Benjamini-Hochberg would help with this (controls FDR).
As said earlier ICC is for numeric data (at least interval) and not for ordinal data (computing means and standard deviations is debatable for Likert data).
Most other measures of inter-rater agreement assume same number of observations between the raters (the same raters” rate the same “objects”; here you have different raters rating the same objects. So that rules out all the kappa’s, alpha’s, etc.
For reference , you may want to read this post, which has many sources and links. The suggestion is to use Kendall's W statistic and test, which works on ranks and is well suited for ordinal data. But as far as I know, Kendall does not work when you have different numbers of raters per group. You could also use something like Krippendorff's alpha. But this does not make use of the ordinal nature of the data. So you are losing information. I can not say how badly it would affect the power. And it still faces the issue of different number of ratings accross groups. You may also benefit from this paper (specific to ordinal data, using a GLMM). The R implementation seems to be "an exercise left to the student". And the issue of different number of ratings per group remains.
You could aggregate all the ratings per group (e.g. means - which is debatable for Likert data), but then you only have a single datapoint per group. Or you could replicate (by sampling with replacement) the ratings from a given department, until the number of ratings is equal to the total employee count in your sample. And then you could use the methods mentioned above. But that does not feel right; we are adding autocorrelation, artificially inflating the size of the departmental samples, etc. Maybe other contributors can comment, but I would not recommend this. Or I could down-sample the “company overall” data, to get the same number of observations as a given department. But that is throwing data away; so not a good idea.
So far, I tried to see if one could use some of the various methods for measures of agreement, but did pretty much fail, either because the data is ordinal, or because the number of observations are different. So let's look at good old $\chi^2$ and contingency tables, which handle these different numbers of observations.
To start with get the counts of each score, separately by question and by department (say you have e.g. 8 departments). One may be tempted to use an 9x5 contingency matrix for each question, with Fisher-exact, or $\chi^2$ tests. But the data in the table is not independent (in fact, if you have the 8 totals for each department, you now have the company total i.e. the sum of these 8 values). So you have to use one of the options above for the independence issue (“rest of the company?”).
To then answer your question more directly, you can run a 2x5 contingency matrix, comparing each department, to the “company” (however you decided to represent it), for each question; definitively use a multiple comparison correction.
Note also that contingency tables do not make use of the ordinal nature of your data. How bad is that?
So this leads me to Mann-Whitney U test, or rather Brunner-Munzel test (BMt), which handles the case of unequal variances. This is a test of stochastic inequality; i.e. the null here is $P(X > Y) = P(Y > X)$ or $P(X > Y) + 0.5 · P(X = Y) = 0.5$. That is, if you randomly pick a value from group 1 ($X$) and from group 2 ($Y$), the $X$ value will be just as often larger than it will be smaller. Alternatively, the $X$ value will more often than not larger (or smaller) than the $Y$ value. That will tell you if a department rated one question higher (or lower) than the “company”. BMt makes use of the ordinal nature of the data, but still requires you to run multiple 2-samples tests with MCC (hence power reduction).\
TL:DR; Brunner-Munzell, with an adjustment to be made about how to represent the company as a whole.
